# Where do i change the my.cnf on mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, my.cnf

I'm trying to change the `max_allowed_packet` setting on mysql cluster (version 7.4.8) - i have 5 nodes

- 2x SQL Node
- 2x Data Node
- 1x Managament Node

I have updated the `my.cnf` on **all** of the servers ->

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
ndbcluster
ndb-connectstring=manager-db
default_storage_engine=ndbcluster
port=3306
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
```

But `show variables like '%max_allowed_packet%'` still returns `524288000`

What am i doing wrong ? where do i need to set it ?

Comment: This logically needs to be done on SQL nodes where MySQL services are installed and you need to see what show global variables to verify the value and you can change the value on fly as well using set global max_allowed_packet..hope it helps

Comment: @NawazSohail yep your right - the reason i didnt see the change was as my answer below - needed to restart the client session !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is indeed the SQL Nodes - the key factor is related to the client - the setting doesn't apply until you close the client session and reopen it